# Is providing a cryptographically secure token that only works for one request secure enough for a web service?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, authorization

I am creating a REST service that is dealing with sensitive data. It will be over SSL, and all request content going both ways will be additionally encrypted.

For authorization, I was planning on making it so a client initially logs in and gets a token, and then they have to provide this token on their next request. Each and every request they do returns a new token. Each token may only be used once.

Is this a secure enough authorization scheme? I've looked at other techniques, such as how Amazon does it for AWS, but it seems like request signing adds a ton of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

SSL-without-additional-encryption is secure enough. You can verify that the server provides a particular certificate, instead of "any certificate signed by a trusted CA", for resistance against MITM attacks. Sometimes requests are signed with HMAC; a secret is transmitted over SSL, and then follow-on requests are transmitted unencrypted but signed. HMAC request signing is not complicated, but if you are transmitting everything over SSL (not just an initial secret) then there is no point.